# jQuery failing on certain pages

Tags: jquery, wordpress

Anyone have any idea why my jQuery carousel is working fine at the bottom of [my home](http://www.brettgolding.com/planetpole/) page but not on my [workshops and event pages](http://www.brettgolding.com/planetpole/?page_id=10)? I have tried noConflict but to no avail.

Comment: you're not exactly the one to accept answers, are you? 0 out of 9 questions accepted...

Comment: You'd need to start accepting answers soon, or you won't really get any answers. Teachers need recognition, too. Look at fbfcn's link for more info.

Comment: No probs Reno was just an oversight wasn't sure how the site works. Thanks for making me aware :)

Comment: So if it sucks, why don't you give ideas on how it won't sucks anymore?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You initialise your plugin with `jQuery('div#image_list ul.image_list').jj_ngg_shuffle();`
but there seems to be no object that has an id of `image_list`.

The javascript error I'm getting is: `Object has not method 'jj_ngg_shuffle'` which confirms this.

Comment: Ok but I am not sure how it is working then on the home page?